# Posted Wall link doesn't get parsed by Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala, koala-gem

I'm using Ruby on Rails ails with the Koala gem to post a link to the users wall.

My Koala method looks like this:

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(user.oauth_token)
graph.put_wall_post('', {
  link: "http://myfqd.com"
});
```

The link gets posted but there is no title, no description just the url gets displayed in the box.

The page which is getting posted is totally valid with all the og tags and stuff. Already debugged it with facebooks debugger.

Is it in general not possible to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I never seen such case that a page is accessible to Facebook (al dandy in fb debugger) and yet it's improperly displayed on Facebook. I suggest you double check if Facebook really can access this page, etc. Also take a look at the logs, maybe some hint there.

Answer (score 0):

There are parameters you can include to show or override the title, caption, description and picture. The method should look like this:

```
@graph.put_wall_post("message", 
{
  name: "title",
  caption: "caption",
  description: "description",
  link: "https://www.url.com/", 
  picture: "https://www.url.com/assets/image.png"
}, "me")
```

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed#